# Setting Selenium Webdriver to run with Task Scheduler when user isn't logged in?

Tags: python, selenium, windows-task-scheduler

Currently I am able to run a batch script that launches a webdriver via Python **when** I select the option within task scheduler `Run only when user is logged in`

However, if I selected `Run whether user is logged in or not`, webdriver doesn't get launched.
If I look at task scheduler under this option, I see the task is "running" but no outcome. Additionally, the task status remains "running" with no apparent end. So it must be stuck in some strange loop where imagined lauch doesn't end.

I have all neccesary options checked:

1. Run with Highest privileges
2. Wake the PC up to run the batch

Here is the batch_file:

```
SET logfile="logs\firefox.log"
@echo off
SET start = %time%
@echo Starting data Script at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
"C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" "D:\DATABASE\data\transcripts\batch scripts\launch_selenium_test.py"
pause
@echo finished data at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
@echo. >> %logfile%
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done same - using my own code, and indeed it does run - I could see chromedriver and chrome.exe in task scheduler, and wifi / memory usage in resource monitor.  I even had diagnostics for the webpages I was 'scraping' save to file - however, these relied upon specific chrome extensions (activated via shortcut keys) - which I do not believe were operating correctly so the output data showed 0 search results (although captured everything else including driver details etc.)